# Запуск Python приложения на Windows у которого нет python интерпретатора

Tags: python, windows

Как запускать python приложения на windows , учитывая что на этом ПК нет интерпретатора ?

Comment: можно компилировать в исполняемые файлы, тема компиляции программ на python уже поднималась на хэшкоде, воспользуйтесь поиском

Answer (score 4):

Никак. В любом случаи или придётся ставить интерпретатор (тогда скрипты сразу по умолчанию с расширением .py буду запускаться интерпретатором), или создавать контейнер, который будет включать в себя интерпретатор. Например py2exe.

Answer (score 3):

`cx_freeze` или `pyinstaller` или `py2exe` вам помогут.

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать библиотеки питона (его возможность встраиваться в программы) и откомпилировать приложение